# Problem to modify web.config in runtime

Tags: feature-activation, web-config, spwebconfigmodification

I'm trying to modify the web.config file when the feature is activated with the code below:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite).WebApplication;

    SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification("mode", "system.web/customErrors");
    modification.Owner = "modifyAccountFeatureOwner";
    modification.Sequence = 0;
    modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureAttribute;
    modification.Value = "Off";         
    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);

    webApp.Update();            
    webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications(); 
}
```

But I'm receiving this error in the step Activate Features:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': '' is an invalid expression.

Anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification() 
myModification.Path = "system.web/customErrors";
myModification.Name = "mode";

Comment: Manipulating the `web.configs` can be a painful job. Is PowerShell an option instead of server-side code?

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite).WebApplication;

    SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification();
    modification.Path = "configuration/system.web/customErrors"
    modification.Name = "mode"
    modification.Owner = "modifyAccountFeatureOwner";
    modification.Sequence = 0;
    modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureAttribute;
    modification.Value = "Off"; 
    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Clear()        
    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);

    webApp.Update();            
    webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but didn't work.

Comment: what error you are getting, could you please share complete lof